# How to Auto-run construct in parent class without call from child class

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I'm searching for a way to call a parent class constructor(?) auto-magically from a child class:

*(Note: This is just an example, so typing errors may be present)*

```
Class myParent()
{
    protected $html;

    function __construct( $args )
    {
        $this->html = $this->set_html( $args );
    }

    protected function set_html( $args )
    {
        if ( $args['foo'] === 'bar' )
            $args['foo'] = 'foobar';
        return $args;
    }
}

Class myChild extends myParent
{
    public function do_stuff( $args )
    {
        return $this->html;
    }
}

Class myInit
{
    public function __construct( $args )
    {
        $this->get_stuff( $args );
    }

    public function get_stuff( $args )
    {
        $my_child = new myChild();
        print_r( $my_child->do_stuff( $args ) );
    }
}

$args = array( 'foo' => 'bar, 'what' => 'ever' );
new myInit( $args );

// Should Output:
/* Array( 'foo' => 'foobar', 'what' => 'ever' ) */
```

What I want to avoid is having to call (inside Class myChild) `__construct( $args ) { parent::__construct( $args ); }`.

Question: Is this possible? If so: How?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you opposed to calling `parent::__construct()`?

Comment: I'd like PHP to magically write my application too.

Comment: @Wesley van Opdorp Please see the solution. Works for me. @Charles Sprayberry I got a base class that gets extended by an unknown number of child classes and therefore I have to run a standard procedure for all input arguments (like dropping invalid input, parsing defaults, etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your sample code, myParent::__construct will already get called wen instanciating myChild.
To get your code to work as you want simply change

```
public function get_stuff( $args )
{
    $my_child = new myChild();
    print_r( $my_child->do_stuff( $args ) );
}
```

by

```
 public function get_stuff( $args )
    {
        $my_child = new myChild($args);
        print_r( $my_child->do_stuff() );
    }
```

**As long as myChild has no constructor**, the parent constructor will be called / inherited.

Comment: Perfect. +1. I haven't known that I can drop it into the class and the parent constructor get's called. Thanks

Comment: `As long as myChild has no constructor, the parent constructor will be called / inherited.` Thank you sooo much! I've searched a lot to find this simple statement describing perfectly what's going on!

Answer (score 5):

As `Child` has no constructor present and *extends* `Parent`, any time `new Child()` is specified the `Parent` constructor will be **implicitly** called.

If you do specify a `Child` constructor then you have to use specify `parent::__construct();` inside the `Child` constructor as it will not be called implicitly.

**N.B** When defining a constructor in a subclass it is best practice to call `parent::__construct()` on the first line of the method definition so that any instance parameters and state inherited is set prior to subclass initiation.